# Install different versions of software

Tags: versions, software-sources

A particular software (GRASS GIS) I need is available in two different versions - stable(6.4.0) and unstable(7.0). Stable one is available in Ubuntu repository while developmental one can be installed from SVN. My question is can I have both installed in same machine? Will it cause problems in operation? Later if I need to uninstall the SVN installed version how can I do it?

Comment: If you edit your question to mention what the "particular software" is, we'd most likely be able to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: It depends on the software.What software you would like to install??you could just install the one from svn to a different prefix, like /opt/package-unstable and when you HAVE to have it you call /opt/package-unstable/bin/package (replacing 'package' appropriately')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem. The one from repository will be installed to default location. The one from SVN will need to be compiled, and then you can copy the binaries/other files to any location manually or using `make install` (if available). So compile the one from SVN and install(copy) it to ~/bin or any location other than where the one from repo installs and should be good to go.